# How avoid closing EntityManager when OptimisticLockException occurs?

Tags: doctrine-orm, transactions, optimistic-locking

My problem - process try change entity that already changed and have newest version id. When i do flush() in my code in UnitOfWork's commit() rising OptimisticLockException and catching in same place by catch-all block. And in this catch doctrine closing EntityManager. 
If i want skip this entity and continue with another from ArrayCollection, i should not use flush()?

Try recreate EntityManager:

```
}catch (OptimisticLockException $e){
    $this->em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    echo "\n||OptimisticLockException.";
    continue;
}
```

And still get

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]   
The EntityManager is closed.
```

Strange.

If i do

```
$this->em->lock($entity, LockMode::OPTIMISTIC, $entity->getVersion());
```

and then do flush() i get OptimisticLockException and closed entity manager.
if i do

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->resetManager();
$em = $doctrine->getManager();
```

Old data unregistered with this entity manager and i even can't write logs in database, i get error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
Notice: Undefined index: 00000000514cef3c000000002ff4781e
```

Comment: Or i must reopen EntityManager in catch block in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You should check entity version before you try to flush it to avoid exception. In other words you should not call flush() method if the lock fails.

You can use `EntityManager#lock()` method for checking whether you can flush entity or not.

```php
    /** @var EntityManager $em */
    $entity = $em->getRepository('Post')->find($_REQUEST['id']);

    // Get expected version (easiest way is to have the version number as a hidden form field)
    $expectedVersion = $_REQUEST['version'];

    // Update your entity
    $entity->setText($_REQUEST['text']);

    try {
        //assert you edit right version
        $em->lock($entity, LockMode::OPTIMISTIC, $expectedVersion);

        //if $em->lock() fails flush() is not called and EntityManager is not closed 
        $em->flush();
    } catch (OptimisticLockException $e) {
        echo "Sorry, but someone else has already changed this entity. Please apply the changes again!";
    }
```

Check the example in Doctrine docs [optimistic locking](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking)

Comment: Add info in question.

Comment: I read that in docs, i understand that. I don't want echo "sorry" information and stop working. I get a lot of data and i don't want request all data again because of single entity. In catch block EntityManager is closed. Ok, i can reset it and create again. But all data unregistered in new EntityManager and i can't work with this data anymore.

Comment: In my example I did the lock() check only for one entity, but in your case you need to do the check for all entities in your collection. If the lock for some entity fails, you need to decide how to solve it (reload the entity from database, warn user etc.). You should not call flush() when any entity didn't pass the lock check.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, nearly 4 years later, Doctrine is still unable to recover from an optimistic lock properly.

Using the `lock` function as suggested in the doc doesn't work if the db was changed by another server or php worker thread. The `lock` function only makes sure the version number wasn't changed by the current php script since the entity was loaded into memory. It doesn't read the db to make sure the version number is still the expected one.

And even if it did read the db, there is still the potential for a race condition between the time the `lock` function checks the current version in the db and the flush is performed.

Consider this scenario:

- server A reads the entity,
- server B reads the same entity,
- server B updates the db,
- server A updates the db <== optimistic lock exception

The exception is triggered when `flush` is called and there is nothing that can be done to prevent it.

Even a pessimistic lock won't help unless you can afford to loose performance and actually lock your db for a (relatively) long time.

Doctrine's solution (`update... where version = :expected_version`) is good in theory. But, sadly, Doctrine was designed to become unusable once an exception is triggered. **Any** exception. Every entity is detached. Even if the optimistic lock can be easily solved by re-reading the entity and applying the change again, Doctrine makes it very hard to do so.

Comment: It is not as easy as it might look. When *LockException is thrown Doctrine closes entity manager to avoid unexpected data inconsistency.

There is no one generic way how to recover from it because it depends on your use case and you can have different strategies on how to recover e.g. reread, apply changes, override changes, discard changes, notify user, restart bacth script etc.

This is the reason why recovering from can not be implemented in the library

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, sometimes `EntityManager#lock()` is not useful. In my case, the Entity version may change during the same request.

If `EntityManager` closes after `flush()`, I proceed like this:

```php
if (!$entityManager->isOpen()) {
    $entityManager = EntityManager::create(
        $entityManager->getConnection(),
        $entityManager->getConfiguration(),
        $entityManager->getEventManager()
    );

    // ServiceManager shoud be aware of this change
    // this is for Zend ServiceManager your shoud adapt this part to your usecase
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
    $serviceManager->setService(EntityManager::class, $entityManager);
    $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(false);

    // Then you should manually reload every Entity you need (or repeat the whole set of actions)
}
```